# Creating transfer edges in multimodal network dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, multimodal-network

I have three feature classes: `Bus Stops`, `Routes` and `Streets`. The points are not coincident on vertices of either of the line feature classes - they are located next to the routes (red line):
[image: Example data]

The line feature classes are not coincident at end points - they were digitised as long lines mostly, intersecting each other. The routes were traced along the roads. At first I thought the line feature classes were going to be a problem, but according to [this excellent blog post](http://www.aubreyrhea.net/gis/index.php/2010/05/preparing-street-data-to-become-a-network-dataset/), setting my connectivity as `Any Vertex` during the creation of the network dataset will solve that problem by creating junctions where any of the lines intersect.

My problem is that I want to create a multimodal network dataset, with the `Routes` representing the routes the bus would travel, and `Streets` are where pedestrians would walk. `Bus Stops` represent the transfer points where the pedestrian could stop walking along the streets and start travelling on a bus route.

According to page 33 of the slides from the Network Analyst technical workshop at [this year's Esri conference](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc12/tech-workshops/tw_67.pdf), it says I will need to create transfer edges between the stop and the route, so that the two are 'connected'.

How do I create these edges i.e. is there a setting in the network dataset creation wizard where I have to specify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are basically wanting a 2-mode network dataset with the bus stops as transfer points, so you have a couple of options.

First, the bus stops need to be in some way connected to the network at a vertex (on both layers). If the bus route overlaps the streets then a transfer edge is unnecessary and as long as the point is snapped to a vertex on both layers it will transfer. Then, in the connectivity panel of the network dataset, you create two modes or layers. One is the bus routes, one is the streets, and then the point class (bus stops) have both checked.

If the bus routes do not overlap the streets, you manually create a line feature class from the bus stops on the street to a point on the bus route line. These need to be snapped to vertices as well. Then, the transfer points would be at either end on the respective street and bus route sides of the line.

The Esri "Paris" gdb would help explain some of this and I believe it comes with Desktop.

Comment: I have done the Network Analyst Tutorial, but the multimodal example is quite simplified. My routes overlap the streets, but the stops do not touch the lines at all. Would I now have to draw lines from the stops and snap the endpoints of these lines onto the routes?

Comment: If you want to use the stops as they are, then you will have to create a transfer line between the routes/streets and the stop point. 

Alternatively, the stops themselves need to be snapped to the network edge features (streets/bus routes) if you want to use them as transfer points between modes. If the routes are overlapping the streets, just make sure that you have a vertex on each place that the stops. This would eliminate creating a transfer line class because your routes/streets already overlap.

Comment: Just to be clear - seeing as the roads/routes have the same vertices, and most of them were digitised as single lines with only start and endpoints, I would have to first snap the bus stops to the roads, and then insert vertices on the roads and routes which are coincident with the stops?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct. You might also try the "Planarize" tool, but I am not sure that it works with points. I'll do a quick test and see and get back to you.

Comment: Planarize is only with lines. However, you could use the "Split line at points" tool in Data Management>Features and use your bus stops (after you snap them to the edge of the streets/routes) as the point input. If you do this for both the streets and the routes, it will create vertices where the stops are.