# Does multimodal network need physical intersection between point (terminal) and line (rail or road)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, routing, multimodal-network

I have created a network dataset with rail, road, and intermodal terminals and set up the connectivity so that you can only travel in-between the two at the terminals. Terminals realistically can be hundreds of yards long and wide, and can connect to multiple roads and rails. It makes sense that my points are located between rail and road but none of them are intersected, so I cannot traverse through both segments. I am working with all of North America so manually creating lines is out of the question. I would think to be realistic that I should not have to connect them, and ArcMap would pick up on this (in an ideal world).

Also help with setting parameters for terminals that transfer one way or both ways between rail and road would be beneficial as well.

Comment: Your dataset is quite large though, so I'm not sure how easily you would be able to create transfer edges. Are the terminals polygons or points?

Answer (score 3):

You will most likely need to [create transfer edges](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37383/creating-transfer-edges-in-a-multimodal-network-dataset). I have found the [ESRI help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Understanding_connectivity/004700000009000000/) on this topic to be quite informative, as well as the [2nd exercise](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_2_Creating_a_multimodal_network_dataset/00470000005v000000/) in the Network Analyst tutorial.

Comment: I also have polygon terminals, but looking at them they do not connect as well. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am trying to get the transfer edges and what I have done is used the near tool to get XY coordinates for the closest rail segment, and repeated for the closest road segment to each of my facilities. So I have my facility data, Rail ID, Rail XY, Road ID, and Road XY in my attribute table. Is there a way to now draw a line to each of the XY coordinates for all my facilities and create a node at the end of the segment?

Comment: I have not (as yet) had to create transfer edges myself, but if you take a look at [this post over at the Network Analyst forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/44773-transit-transfer-penalty?p=254592&viewfull=1#post254592), it looks like it will do what you need.